# wordpress| span tag Takes place is invisible

Tags: css, wordpress

All the trouble started that I could not press the right arrow of the gallery (right arrow appears in the picture)

I saw that only if I move the bar to the right side, just so I'm able to click on the arrow.

As you can see I opened F12 in Firefox, I pointed to the right part of the site.

I saw that it was empty and the area is disturbing.

When I add a SPAN tag
There is another empty space is inserted as the picture above

How do I delete this profit, and how do I increase the wild side?

Please can you help me?

this is the web address

www.aravrefael.net

tnx a lot 

the img link is :
http://i62.tinypic.com/96kbxz.png

```
  <style type="text/css">.sideside{float: right;top:-162em;right:-17em;position:relative;}</style>
<span class="sideside">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</span>
```

tnx

Comment: dont clearly understand what problem is..

Comment: Did you see the picture attached?
There is another invisible part
How do I delete it?

This is the code:  <style type="text/css">.sideside{float: right;top:-162em;right:-17em;position:relative;}</style>
<span class="sideside">
        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</span>

Comment: remove it from template or add { display: none } rule to hide it

Comment: What does that mean remove it from tamplate?

Comment: find this string <span class="sideside"><?php get_sidebar(); ?></span> in PHP code and delete or comment it O_o

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2aexz78.png <br /> now how can i move it right?and Not create that empty space?

Comment: http://i61.tinypic.com/2aexz78.jpg  Currently the side bar of this arrived:

How do I move it to the right without creating the same empty space?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use plugin "raw data" in wordpress